# DatePickerDialog cannote resolve symbol

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepickerdialog

All written DatePickerDialog report an error (cannot resolve symbol), but the program is compiled correctly, no error in the LogCat. Who can explain why?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should try the **Invalidate Caches / Restart** option on the **File** menu. A stale cache is the cause of many unresolved reference problems that are actually there.